# error with friendly URL with .htaccess and relative files

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

i made a .htaccess file to make my URL looks from
http://www.domain.com/ar/?page=article&id=20
to
http://www.domain.com/ar/article/20

i have made it so far with

```
Options -ExecCGI +Includes -IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /ar/?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

BUT ..
all the files (css,js,images) are broken .. i have tried to make it absolute as much as i can (by adding / to the beginning of each of its src) with no luck

..
how to get the files loaded ?

how to redirect urls from (?page=contact to ar/contact .. not to ar/topic/20/?page=contact)?

and how to involve any other unexpected parameters in my url ??

Comment: Not got your last words?

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure, but try this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# with html base href in header: <base href="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/" />
RewriteBase /
# deny rules to url rewrite for specific file types in website root folder
RewriteRule ^/?(.*).(php|css|ico|js|log|png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$ - [L]
# deny rules to url rewrite for folders (if needed)
RewriteRule ^(css|images)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and the mapping rule. index.php is your basic file for example
# $1 -> ar/ $2 -> article/$3 -> 20
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&id=$3 [L]
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition to the rewrite rule. Try this.

```
Options -ExecCGI +Includes -IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css¦jpg¦gif¦png¦js)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /ar/?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

This will only rewrite the URL if the requested file doesn't has an extension of CSS,JPG,GIF,PNG, or JS.

**EDIT** Corrected a grammar mistake.